# How to get subselect to reference anothersub select in same query

Tags: sql-server

I have a (slow) query that almost does what I want.  The **bold** section is the pseudo-code I am trying to add.  The goal of this query is to get a single row per custnumber with 5 columns of data:

- colA: MKT
- colB: custnumber
- colC: most recent apptdate WHERE src_id = Loss Recovery AND dsp_id = Sale
- colD: most recent apptdate WHERE src_id NOT= Loss Recovery AND dsp_id NOT= Sale **and this apptdate is earlier than LRSale**
- colE: days between NoSale and LRSale

This is what I have built so far, close to working.  I have tried several different ways to get the last bit in but am having real trouble parsing the syntax to make it work right.

```
SELECT DISTINCT *, DATEDIFF(day,NoSale,LRSold) AS 'Diff'
FROM(SELECT a.MKT,
    a.custnumber,        
    (SELECT TOP 1 CAST(apptdate AS DATE)
        FROM prospectissues b
        WHERE b.custnumber = a.custnumber
        **AND b.apptdate < c.apptdate**
        AND b.src_id <> 'Loss Recovery' AND b.dsp_id <> 'Sale'
        ORDER BY apptdate DESC) AS 'NoSale',
    (SELECT TOP 1 CAST(apptdate AS DATE)
        FROM prospectissues c
        WHERE c.custnumber = a.custnumber
        AND c.src_id = 'Loss Recovery' AND c.dsp_id = 'Sale'
        ORDER BY apptdate DESC) AS 'LRSold'      

FROM prospectissues a
WHERE CAST(apptdate AS DATE) >= DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy,0,GETDATE())-3,0)) z
WHERE LRSold IS NOT NULL
```

Thank you, I appreciate any insight!  I'm sure it's something simple that I'm just too tired to see right now.  Been banging my head against this for too long.

-edit 7/25

I cannot write to the database, only run Select queries.
Here is a sample of the table I'm working with (rows numbered just for easy reference):

```
     | MKT | custnumber | dsp_id  | src_id         | ApptDate |
     ----------------------------------------------------------
 1   | CLE | 14675      | PMPrice | Email          | 3/7/20   |
 2   | CLE | 14675      | Sale    | Radio          | 3/9/20   |
 3   | CLE | 246466     | NH      | Prior Customer | 3/7/20   |
 4   | PIT | 284747     | PMPrice | Show           | 3/7/20   |
 5   | PIT | 284747     | Sale    | Loss Recovery  | 3/12/20  |
 6   | PIT | 384603     | Sale    | SelfGen        | 3/3/20   |
 7   | PIT | 384603     | Sale    | Loss Recovery  | 3/8/20   |
 8   | COL | 384764     | PMPrice | Website        | 3/15/22  |
 9   | COL | 384921     | Sale    | Website        | 3/22/20  |
10   | COL | 385052     | PMPrice | Show           | 3/7/20   |
11   | COL | 385052     | Sale    | Aggregates     | 3/10/20  |
12   | COL | 385052     | Sale    | Loss Recovery  | 3/18/20  |
13   | PIT | 385662     | OVB     | Aggregates     | 3/12/20  |
14   | PIT | 385662     | Sale    | Loss Recovery  | 3/21/20  |
15   | PIT | 385662     | PMPrice | Store          | 4/15/20  |
```

Sample of desired output:

```
| MKT | custnumber | NoSale  | LRSold  | Diff |
----------------------------------------------
| PIT | 284747     | 3/7/20  | 3/12/20 | 5    |
| COL | 385052     | 3/7/20  | 3/18/20 | 11   |
| PIT | 385662     | 3/12/20 | 3/21/20 | 9    |
```

The goal is to visualize how long a time gap (days) exists between Non-sale (NS) records and Loss Recovery - Sale (LR) records.

NS = anything with dsp_id NOT equal to 'Sale' AND src_id NOT equal to 'Loss Recovery' counts as an NS record

LR = anything with dsp_id = 'Sale' AND src_id = 'Loss Recovery'

criteria are:

- MKT: simple text, this will always be consistent between records with the same custnumber
- custnumber: the "key column", always an integer
- NoSale: the most recent NS apptdate prior to a LR apptdate sharing the same custnumber
- LRSale: the most recent LR record grouped by custnumber
- Diff: days between NS and LR

Seems simple in theory, but giving me a hell of a time.

Comment: The short answer is you can't. You will need to restructure the query. And it might be a good idea to start over. Multiple subqueries that refer to the same table (and no other) as the outer query with almost identical logic is a concern. Using DISTINCT is a concern - especially since you include all columns from the table. Perhaps conditional aggregation might be possible. Better suggestions require more detailed knowledge of what your table represents and what your actual goal is. The derived table does not serve any real purpose here.

Comment: Could you add a `create table` statement to give us some schema to work with, an `insert` to populate the table with some sample data, and a table showing your expected output based on the sample data? At first glance this looks like a use case for `apply`, but without that extra information we would have to make a bunch of guesses.

Comment: What about records that have dsp_id of Sale, but src_id is not Loss Recovery. Or vice versa: src_id is Loss Recovery, but dsp_id is not Sale? Either of these types of record won't fit with either category. In the sample data, rows 2, 6, 9, 11 don't fit anywhere based on the described logic.

Comment: Correct.  Those rows should be ignored since they do not meet the criteria.  The only interest is pulling out those records that result in non-sales to LR Sales and calculating the days between them.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will do it. We use **conditional aggregation** to help simplify the initial pass, including grabbing the first computed column (`LRSold`), but we still use a couple layers of nesting to get `NoSale` and then the `Diff()`. We could definitely eliminate one layer of nesting, but then we'd have to repeat the entire nested query from the `SELECT` clause to compute the diff, and it's a small result set, so this is probably better:

```
SELECT *, 
    DATEDIFF(day, NoSale, LRSold) [Diff]
FROM (
    SELECT *,
       (
          SELECT  MAX(pi0.apptdate)
          FROM prospectissues pi0
          WHERE pi0.custnumber = t.custnumber AND pi0.MKT = t.MKT AND pi0.apptdate < t.LRSold 
              AND pi0.src_id <> 'Loss Recovery' and pi0.dsp_id <> 'Sale'
          GROUP BY pi0.custnumber, pi0.MKT
     ) NoSale
    FROM (
        SELECT pi.custnumber, pi.MKT, 
            MAX(CASE WHEN pi.src_id = 'Loss Recovery' and pi.dsp_id = 'Sale' THEN apptdate END) As LRSold
        FROM prospectissues pi
        WHERE apptdate >= DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy,0,GETDATE())-3,0) 
        GROUP BY pi.custnumber, pi.MKT
        HAVING MAX(CASE WHEN pi.src_id = 'Loss Recovery' and pi.dsp_id = 'Sale' THEN apptdate ELSE NULL END) IS NOT NULL
    ) t
)d 
WHERE NoSale IS NOT NULL
```

See it here:

> https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a41b9191cef92247b722788d6474edc2

I feel like we could do better with a lateral join (`APPLY`) to reduce the number of trips into the table, and often if that works there is also a Windowing function solution that will work even better. But this is what you get for free.

Finally, one thing I noticed is casting `appdate` into a DATE value. Given the reliance of the query on this field, this cast is **very bad for performance**, because it breaks any chance of using an index on the field and the way the query was structured forced the database you to *run the conversion **multiple times** for every row in the table...* even rows that will not be used for the results.

If the column is a `datetime` or `datetime2` this is easily fixed: don't do the cast. It's not needed for the query to work properly. But if this is a `varchar` column, you need to **FIX** the schema, because [it really is **BROKEN**](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2022/07/13/sql-and-dates/). The performance issue here is just one of several reasons why, but it is effective at demonstrating why it's so important: just that one change to the column type would likely cut the execution time of the original query by more than an order of magnitude. **NEVER** use string-typed columns to store time-typed data.

Comment: The WHERE clause limits the LR to the last 3 years, and the NS should only be pulling non-sale dates from before LR anyways, so it does not need to be modified in the WHERE clause.  Any row that does not meet the LR or NS criteria should be skipped as the only data I am really trying to isolate is the days between NS and LR.  Apptdate is stored as datetime even thought there is no time aspect at all.  I wish I could modify the schema but I do not have that sort of access.  I did not know casting it would be so volatile, so thank you.

Comment: If you're seeing "both", you're seeing the old answer. I just updated it this morning with the corrected query.

Comment: I just wrapped it in a WHERE nosale < lrsold and it seems to be working a treat!  Thank you for helping me figure this out!  I don't have enough rep to upvote, but this worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for. It should run quicker by using aggregates like `Min` instead of `order by` and `top 1`.

```
SELECT ns.MKT, ns.custnumber, 
       ns.MinDate AS NoSale, lr.MinDate AS LRSold
       DATEDIFF(day, ns.MinDate, lr.MinDate) AS Diff
FROM (SELECT MKT, custnumber, min(apptdate) as MinDate 
      FROM prospectissues
      WHERE src_id <> 'Loss Recovery' AND dsp_id <> 'Sale'
      GROUP BY MKT, custnumber) ns
    INNER JOIN --should be similar outcome as WHERE LRSold IS NOT NULL
     (SELECT MKT, custnumber, min(apptdate) MinDate 
      FROM prospectissues b
      WHERE src_id = 'Loss Recovery' AND dsp_id = 'Sale'
      GROUP BY MKT, custnumber) lr 
    ON ns.custnumber = lr.custnumber AND ns.MKT = lr.MKT
      AND ns.apptdate < lr.apptdate --The new part that you want
WHERE CAST(ns.MinDate AS DATE) >= DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy,0,GETDATE())-3,0)
```

Comment: Unsure what to do with this as it's getting syntax errors?  a.MKT, a.custnumber, but where is a identified?  I am not skilled enough to parse this I think.

Comment: Oh. (sorry, I don't have a means to test this query). You're right. I omitted table "A". I fixed the query to use "ns", which should have the same result.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if your data has any anomalies. You might want to consider an analytic approach.

```
with data1 as (
    select MKT, custnumber, apptdate,
        case when src_id <> 'Loss Recovery' and dsp_id <> 'Sale' then 'NS'
             when src_id  = 'Loss Recovery' and dsp_id  = 'Sale' then 'LR'
        end as flag
    from prospectissues
    where apptdate >= datefromparts(year(getdate()) - 3, 1, 1)
), data2 as (
    select *,
        case when flag = 'NS' then cast(apptdate as date) end NS,
        case when flag = 'LR' then cast(apptdate as date) end LR,
        count(case when flag = 'LR' then 1 end)
            over (partition by MKT, custnumber order by apptdate) as LR_cnt
    from data1
    --where flag in ('NS', 'LR') /* possible optimization */
)
select MKT, custnumber,
    max(NS) as NoSale, min(LR) as LRSold, datediff(day, max(NS), min(LR)) as Diff
from data2
where LR_cnt = 0 or flag = 'LR'
group by MKT, custnumber
having max(NS) is not null and min(LR) is not null;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=9246435525b3ca67b3de6377b3a187be